# Trying to create a segue between 2 collectionView cells from different viewController

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, segue

I am trying to create a segue that works like this. When i tap the first cell in my first view controller, i will go to my second view controller and display first cell of my collection view in second view controller. And when i tap second cell in first view controller, i will go to second view controller and display second cell of my collectionview in second view controller. I came this far but it doesn't work.

FIRST VIEW CONTROLLER

```
var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath!

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        selectedIndexPath = indexPath as NSIndexPath
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: self)
        print (selectedIndexPath)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "mySegue"
        {
            let secondVC = segue.destination as! ViewController2
            secondVC.initialDisplayCellIndexPath = selectedIndexPath
        }
    }
```

SECOND VIEW CONTROLLER

```
    var initialDisplayCellIndexPath: NSIndexPath!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: initialDisplayCellIndexPath as IndexPath, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
```

[image]

When i run my app it crashes as soon as i tap one of the cells. This is the error message:

```
<NSIndexPath: 0x600000227200> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

And the error is in this line:

```
self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: initialDisplayCellIndexPath as IndexPath, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of the `!` force-unwrap operator as the "crash if nil" operator and avoid it entirely until you really, **REALLY** understand optionals.

By declaring your `initialDisplayCellIndexPath`variable as type `NSIndexPath!`, or "implicitly unwrapped optional", you guarantee that your app will crash if you ever reference that variable and it's nil. Instead of doing that you should use "if let" optional chaining or a guard statement.

If we are to help you figure out why you're crashing you need to provide the context for that line. What method is it in? What does the call stack look like at the time of the crash?

Comment: And is initialDisplayCellIndexPath nil when you crash?

Comment: Do what I suggest. Convert initialDisplayCellIndexPath from type `NSIndexPath!` to `NSIndexPath?" (from "implicitly unwrapped optional" to a "normal" optional. Then add `if let` optional chaining or a guard statement to test for nil when your `viewWillAppear` method is called.

Comment: Ok i changed it like this `override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if initialDisplayCellIndexPath != nil {
            self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: initialDisplayCellIndexPath as! IndexPath, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
        } else {   
        }` Now my app does not crash. 2nd view controller appears when i tap any of the cells but collectionview in 2nd view controller does not scroll

Comment: So now you need to figure out why `initialDisplayCellIndexPath` is nil. (BTW, don't post code in comments. It's pretty much unreadable.)

Answer (score 0):

try this! The change the "quotations" to your codes.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
 if let segue = "PHOTOARRAY".cellForItem(at:indexPath) {
performSegue(withIdentifier: "SEGUENAME", sender:segue) 
}}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if let cell = sender as? UICollectionViewCell {
if let  indexPath = self."FIRSTCOLLECTIONVIEWNAME".indexPath(for:cell) {
if segue.identifier == "SEGUENAME" {
let controller : "SECONDCOLLECTIONVIEWCLASSNAME" = segue.destination as! "SECONDCOLLECTIONVIEWCLASSNAME"
controller."PHOTOARRAY" = self."PHOTOARRAY[indexPath.row]
}
}
}
}
```